# SemanticUI Multiple select dont post multiple values

Tags: forms, post, semantic-ui, multiple-value

Im using Semantic UI for design and some functionalities and I failed to make multiple value posting in dropdown select - it adds blocks into the select input, but when submitting, posts only numeric string - one of the input values (instead of array). Seems to post the highest number from selection.

Can anyone tell me, how to make it working? (loading previous values works perfect);

```
<select class="ui dropdown" id="subjs" name="subj" multiple>
                <?php
                $selected = $cats->getsubj();
                $subs = $cats->getsubj(true);
                if (isset($subs) && count($subs) > 0)
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($subs); $i++) {
                        $opt = (in_array($subs[$i], $selected)) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
                        ?>
                        <option class="subjs" value="<?php echo $subs[$i]['ID']; ?>" <?php echo $opt; ?>><?php echo $subs[$i]['title']; ?></option>
                        <?php
                    }
                ?>
</select>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
        maxSelections: 2
    });
</script>
```

PHP:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

*the script is listing of categories from database into select as options. Value for each option is it's ID (integer). One article may be liked with more than one category*

**All advices apreciated... Thanx**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for all, who make stupid mistakes, simple add '[]' to the multiple select name parameter to post array.

```
<select name="x[]"></select>
```